# How to properly rotate viewcontrollers in UINavigationController?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, rotation

I have a UINavigationController which's view is embedded into UIViewController. When I rotate the device, NavigationController perfectly received the `willRotate` `didRotate` events. However, any UIViewControllers pushed before the current visible view controller inside UINavigationController does not receive rotation events.

Here is the problem:
While the second viewController is visible in the navigationController, if I rotate the device, ViewController changes it's layout according to the rotation. When I pop the viewcontroller to get back to first view controller, first view controller shows itself according to portrait layout as It doesn't call my re-layouting methods for the rotated view.

I don't want to add observers for rotation change because it normally already behaves correctly as default rotation methods are automatically called normally...

What can I do in this situation?

I have done it by manually calling willRotate function but I don't feel that this is good.

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    UIInterfaceOrientation io=[[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];

    [self willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:io duration:0.3];

    for(int i=0;i<self.childViewControllers.count;i++){
        [[self.childViewControllers objectAtIndex:i]willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:io duration:0.3];
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you need any rotation event observers. However, the `UIViewController` instances in the `UINavigationController` need to be notified about layout changes. This happens automatically if you add your `UINavigationController` to the view controller hierarchy:

```
[yourParentViewController addChildViewController:yourNavigationController];
```

This will make sure that your navigation controller gets notified about layout changes, and will pass this information on to ALL its view controllers.

Then you can simply do your layout in the `UIViewController`'s [`viewDidLayoutSubviews`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/viewDidLayoutSubviews) method (or if you have a subclassed view, in its `layoutSubviews` method.

**Note:** This method requires iOS 5 or higher!

Comment: Thank you Andreas, I have already added the navigationController to parentViewController. It gets notified when rotation happens. But only the visible viewController of navigation controller is notified.

Comment: @frankish Notified how? I've created a test project replicating your case, and autolayout has been working perfectly (when using autoresizingMasks or the `UIView`'s `layoutSubviews` method).

Comment: I move some buttons from the bottom of the screen to the upper right of it, when device is rotated to landscape mode. But if I push some other viewcontroller before rotating the device, after the rotation, I come back to previous viewcontroller by popping current viewcontroller and I see that viewcontroller did not move my buttons to upper right as I do that manually on "willRotate" function. But If I do the same rotation while that view controller is visible. Everything works perfectly.

Comment: @frankish Don't do it in `willRotate`. If you have to do it in the `UIViewController`, do it in the method `viewDidLayoutSubviews`.

Comment: Would you please update the answer with your last comment, because it worked (:

Answer (score 0):

the code you mentioned is not correct.. we should not call call a delegate method explicitly. please implement the below function in the viewControllers you want to have auto rotate feature in. You can also restrict rotations based to the orientations u want by putting a check for permitted orientations.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
       return YES;
}
```